# Conversion of ATP to NADH without creating a proton motive force?

Tags: bioenergetics

Is it possible to convert ATP into NADH and vice versa without first creating a proton motive force? If so by what mechanism is it done?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any enzymes that both oxidize NADH and generate ATP.

However, in the absence of oxygen, many bacteria ferment ethanol and acetate (among other products) to oxidize NADH and produce ATP. ATP is produced by acetate kinase and NADH is consumed by dehydrogenases in the parallel ethanol secretion pathway. Together, these pathways consume (or more accurately, recycle) NADH and generate ATP.

[image: Acetate ethanol fermentation]

http://mmbr.asm.org/content/69/1/124/F6.expansion.html